# VSCode Remote - SSH plugin fails connection to remote server when user name has a space

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-extensions

I'm running VSCode version 1.80.0

My ~/.ssh/config snippet looks like this:

```
Host host

    User "First Last"
```

When attempting a connection to `host` via ssh or VSCode, I am able to connect just fine.

However, after connecting in VSCode I get a failure to create a directory under my home dir:

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/First’: Permission denied

Feels like the mkdir command is not wrapping the `User` from my ssh config in quotes.

Does someone have a work around for this please?

This is on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: you can find a bunch of issue tickets by googling `github vscode issues remote ssh username space`. I think most of them are closed now. I'd suggest that you raise one of your own. If you do, please [edit] your question post here to add a link to it for posterity.